# Lightway authentication services

Tags: authentication, jwt, passwords, keycloak

I recently started developing an app and wanted to address authentication from the start.
My only requirement was the identification of users and authentication methods like "Sign-In with google". Implementing it myself is usually not a good idea when it comes to security topics. Therefore I wanted to start my first attempt with the most known service, KeyCloak. The more I became familiar with KeyCloak, the more dissatisfied I became. It's very heavyweight. Difficult to understand. I don't need most of the features and a test integration is tricky.

So now i'm here writing this post and asking for your opinion.

- Is there a better and lightway alternative to keycloak?
- Should i implement it (f. e. JWT) by myself?
- Should i dig deeper into the keycloak docu?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How about `auth0` which is more popular, well-supported option. You can consider it lightweight because it provides the ready api, and the heavylifting is done in the auth0 servers

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. Auth0 actually looks really cool. The only thing that makes me uneasy is that the data is not stored at my server.